# Turning on antialiasing in Allegro 5 causes objects to rotate and change position (possibly due to memory errors)?

Tags: c, graphics, allegro, allegro5

I have an Allegro project in its early stages, and I have a struct to represent spaceships (a fundamental part of my spaceship game, as you might imagine). That struct is defined as:

```
typedef struct sc_ship_s {
    // Linked List attributes
    struct sc_ship_s *ll_prev;
    struct sc_ship_s *ll_next;
    // Informational attributes
    char name[256];
    char ship_class[256];

    // Physical attributes
    //  Position and velocity
    float posx, posy;
    float velx, vely;
    //  Rotation, in degrees, and rotational velocity, in deg. per second
    float rotation;
    float rotvel;

    // Rendering attributes
    sc_shiprender_t *render_attributes;

} sc_ship_t;
```

Without antialiasing, I have a simple demo that runs so I can test zooming, ship updating, et cetera. It works perfectly, generating alternating colored ships in a line:

[image: The intended behavior of the demo]

However, when I add both of these lines (not just either one; it has to be both) to enable antialiasing:

```
al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 2, ALLEGRO_SUGGEST);
al_set_new_display_option(ALLEGRO_SAMPLES, 4, ALLEGRO_SUGGEST);
```

it looks like this:

[image: The incorrect behavior, which occurs when I enable multibuffer antialiasing]

As you can see, one ship is missing, they are not the correct distance apart, several have a rotational velocity, and one spawned with a rotation already set to about 230 degrees. My code for generating them does not yet set rotation or rotational velocity.

I suspect some kind of memory corruption, because my debug output should be full of lines like this:

```
DEBUG src/ship.c:86: Drawing a ship: CX: 16 CY: 16 Dx: 266.400085 Dy: 286.000000 Deg: 0.000000 Sca: 1.000000
```

and is instead full of lines like this:

```
DEBUG src/ship.c:86: Drawing a ship: CX: 16 CY: 16 Dx: 243.599915 Dy: 260.400085 Deg: -nan Sca: 1.000000

DEBUG src/ship.c:86: Drawing a ship: CX: 16 CY: 16 Dx: 129.199921 Dy: 131.800079 Deg: 2530009767.279658 Sca: 1.000000
```

Last I checked, neither `-nan` nor `2530009767.279658` were equal to 0, the only value Deg (rotation) should ever be at in this particular demo.

Please help? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `struct sc_ship_s *ll_prev;
    struct sc_ship_s *ll_next;`  Is there some reason for cluttering the code with the `ll_` prefix on the two fields?

Comment: without the actual code, we can only guess.   The most likely cause, given the scant info, is that those fields have not been initialized

Comment: @user3629249 No particular reason, no; it's simply a mnemonic for me to notice at a glance that there are linked list operations going on. The attributes in question are initialized to 0 when each new ship is created. I'd post the code, but it;s over 300 lines.

Comment: If you cannot create a minimial,. cleanly compiles code that still displays the problem, then suggest posting to one of the code sites.   I suspect we will not be of any real help with the actual code, so we can compile/link/run it for the purposes of debugging it..   If any special libraries are being used, be sure to post links to those libraries